# To display a read error when the source file is used by other applications while transfering using MQFTE?

Tags: scripting, ant, ibm-mq, websphere-7, websphere-mq-fte

I need to display a read error when the source file is being used by other applications.

For example : Source filename: test.txt Content: Test file.

The above content is stored in the txt file and saved.

The txt file is opened and is modified as below but not saved.

Test file is modified.

When i invoke the transfer now i should get a read error, instead the file gets transferred with the last saved content(Test file).

What can i do to display a error message?

This case was tested in unix and windows.

Comment: On Windows, I am allowed to move a file (using Explorer) that I have open with Notepad. If the OS doesn't make an error, I don't think you'll be able to impose one with Ant.

Comment: Should i consider this a product failure !!!!!!!!!!