# how can we extract the file extension of a file using ant script?

Tags: scripting, ant, ibm-mq, renaming, websphere-mq-fte

The scenario is as follows:

Therea are three files :

test.xls
test.txt
test.doc

I am working with mqfte right now. When these files are transferred to another location the filenames must be as below :

result_xls.txt
result_txt.txt
result_doc.txt

Could anyone help on this?

Can this filename renaming done with ant scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<target name="test">
  <copy todir="dest">
    <fileset dir="src">
      <include name="test*"/>
    </fileset>
    <globmapper from="test.*" to="result_*.txt"/>
  </copy>
</target>
```

Input:

```
  $ find src
  src
  src/test.doc
  src/test.txt
  src/test.xls
```

Output:

```
  $ find dest/
  dest/
  dest/result_doc.txt
  dest/result_txt.txt
  dest/result_xls.txt
```

Comment: Can you suggest something for the below question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870083/to-display-a-read-error-when-the-source-file-is-used-by-other-applications-while

Comment: When i use the following code after a filecopy task in same  target with a filecopy task, it is not working. Note the outcome property is defer in filecopy. is the problem due to outcome=defer.

Comment: I am transferring the file from the source to dest. After reaching the destination i should rename it in the same folder itself.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use the Move Ant Task http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html

Comment: You mean i should  use a glob mapper?. Should there be three different targets? How can i extract the file extension for each file?

Comment: I guess I would have tried the regexp mapper instead of glob, http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html

Comment: tale a look at sudocode's answer, seems he have solved your problem right there :-)